# Secret hangman homework

Tags: python, python-3.x, homework, hangman

Recently I was given homework to make a hangman game, where I wrote the below.
How can I refactor this to use classes?

```
import secrets


def guess_the_word():
    tries_left = 9
    output = ["_"] * len(secret_word)

    print(str(' '.join([letter for letter in output])).strip())

    while tries_left >= 0 and not secret_word == str(''.join([letter for letter in output])):
        # print tries left
        print("\nYou have {} tries left".format(tries_left))
        # display the _ which is length of the secret_word and fill in _ as and when the user 
        # types correct word

        guessed_letter = input("Guess a letter from secret word:")

        if guessed_letter in secret_word:
            print("You guessed correct")
            for i, x in enumerate(secret_word):
                if x is guessed_letter:
                    output[i] = guessed_letter
        else:
            tries_left -= 1
            print("You guessed incorrect")

        print(str(' '.join([letter for letter in output])).strip())


print("\nWelcome to Hangman Game!\n")
# open words.txt file to read words
with open("words.txt") as words_file:
    words_list = words_file.read().split()
# choose a random word from words_list
secret_word = secrets.choice(words_list)
guess_the_word()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I refactor this to use classes?

You don't. There is absolutely no need for that in this program as you don't share a common state between multiple functions. On the same subject, see also [this PyCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

Instead, we should focus on clearing the obvious mistakes made in this function:

1. Be sure to pass information to functions using parameters: global variable can be fine for constants, not so much for information to work on; besides if I `import` your code in an interactive session, I am greeted with a game but any other attempt to call `guess_the_word()` will reuse the same word to guess.
2. This also lead to how you call your code: running the program on the command line will play a game, but `import`ing it will play it too; which may be undesirable. To avoid this side effect, get yourself familiar with the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) construct.
3. [`secrets`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) is a module designed for cryptographically secure sources of random numbers. You don't need such strong randomness here so you can avoid the associated overheads using the simpler [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random) module.
4. You can `join` directly on lists: no need to write a list-comprehension which will just copy the underlying list before feeding it to `join`. In the same vein, `strip`ing whitespace and converting to `str` is superfluous here as the result of `join` already fulfill the two conditions.
5. Checking if a letter is in a string is an \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ operation, so you can skip that and directly perform the iteration over each letter it won't cost more. You can use a flag to know if you have found a matching letter.
6. A message at the end of the while loop to conclude would be a great addition to the user experience.

All in all, this could yield the following code:

```
import random


def guess_the_word(secret_word):
    tries_left = 9
    output = ["_"] * len(secret_word)

    while tries_left >= 0 and secret_word != ''.join(output):
        print(' '.join(output))
        print("\nYou have", tries_left, "tries left")

        guessed_letter = input("Guess a letter from secret word: ")

        found = False
        for i, letter in enumerate(secret_word):
            if guessed_letter == letter:
                output[i] = guessed_letter
                found = True

        if found:
            print("You guessed correct")
        else:
            tries_left -= 1
            print("You guessed incorrect")

    if tries_left < 0:
        print("\nNo more tries, you lose")
    else:
        print("\nCongratz! You found the secret word:", secret_word)


def main(filename="words.txt"):
    print("\nWelcome to Hangman Game!\n")

    with open(filename) as words_file:
        words = words_file.read().split()

    guess_the_word(random.choice(words))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An other nice addition to have is the ability to repeat the games automatically. You could change your `main` part to:

```
def main(filename="words.txt", repeat=sys.maxsize):
    print("\nWelcome to Hangman Game!\n")

    with open(filename) as words_file:
        words = words_file.read().split()

    for _ in range(repeat):
        guess_the_word(random.choice(words))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(repeat=1)
```

to keep the current behaviour but allows `import`ing the file to run `main()` the desired amount of time without having to reload the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Comments about the code in no particular order:

- Dont use global variables
- `[letter for letter in output]` same as output
- `strip()` why do you use this function alot? it just removes white
  space and in this code it it dosent do anything.
- `join()` already returns a string, no need to cast it.

Bugs?

- you can ask for the same letter without getting a penalty.
- just "enter" counts as a "correct" guess.
- you can't guess the whole word.

---

```
class Hangman:
    def __init__(self, word, num_guesses = 9):
        # first take care of init arguments
        self._num_guesses = num_guesses
        self._word = word.lower()
        # after that we define other variables we will be needing
        self._guessed_word = ["_"]*len(word)

    def _guess(self, letter):
        if letter.lower() in self._word:
            for i, c in enumerate(self._word):
                if c is letter:
                    self._guessed_word[i] = letter
            return True
        return False

    def play(self):
        print("\nWelcome to Hangman Game!\n")
        while self._num_guesses > 0:
            letter = input("Guess a letter from the secret word:")
            if self._guess(letter):
                print("You guessed correct")
                if self._word == "".join(self._guessed_word):
                    break
            else:
                self._num_guesses -= 1
                print("You guessed incorrect")
            print(" ".join(self._guessed_word))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = Hangman("codereview")
    h.play()
```